# Storing a List of Booleans in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a list of booleans that are generated which are to be used in the following comparison:

`double equalElements = currentImageHash.Zip(thisPair.Hash, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq) / 256.00;`

Essentially, `currentImageHash` contains a list of 256 bools that are compared to another list of 256 bools- `thisPair` to calculate the percentage of similarity between the two list of bools.

That is the use case-

My question (though- I am willing to take suggestions to improve this process) is how can I go about storing the list of 256 bools in MySQL?

I was thinking about converting it to a string of 1s and 0s, but converting it back and forth seems a bit intensive.

Ideally, storing it in a single column sounds better; having a 1 to 256 relationship for each entry sounds like a normal solution, but  feels really... heavy.

Comment: Are you looking for `blob`/`mediumblob`/`longblob` data type? I found it suitable to store images and files which should be stored as binary data.

Comment: That sounds like the best approach. I think I will need to move everything away from `List<bool>` to proper `byte[]` however. No clue how to do that, but no better time to learn than now!